# What are the precise steps for notarizing an .app file created using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, macos, notarize

I have a simple app named determinant_calculator.app that was created using Python 3.9 along with pyinstaller. It functions fine on my own Mac running OS 11.3.1. I want to share it with others outside the App Store. I have an Apple Developer account but I have no experience as a developer nor have I worked with XCode at all. I'm trying to follow the steps given at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing

I went to the Apple Developer's website and created a certificate, developerID_application.cer, which I downloaded to my desktop. Within Keychain Access, I uploaded the certificate and see it under "My Certificates" as "Developer ID Application: PaulF (47A67S7RBW)"

The bundle contents of determinant_calculator.app contains the info.plist shown here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
      <string>English</string>
      <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
      <string>determinant_calculator</string>
      <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
      <string>determinant_calculator</string>
      <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
      <string>PythonApplet.icns</string>
      <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
      <string>org.pythonmac.unspecified.determinant_calculator</string>
      <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
      <string>6.0</string>
      <key>CFBundleName</key>
      <string>determinant_calculator</string>
      <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
      <string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>0.0.0</string>
<key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
<false/>
<key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>Copyright not specified</string>
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainMenu</string>
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
<key>PyMainFileNames</key>
<array>
    <string>__boot__</string>
</array>
<key>PyOptions</key>
<dict>
    <key>alias</key>
    <true/>
    <key>argv_emulation</key>
    <false/>
    <key>emulate_shell_environment</key>
    <false/>
    <key>no_chdir</key>
    <false/>
    <key>prefer_ppc</key>
    <false/>
    <key>site_packages</key>
    <false/>
    <key>use_faulthandler</key>
    <false/>
    <key>use_pythonpath</key>
    <false/>
    <key>verbose</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>PyResourcePackages</key>
<array/>
<key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
<array>
    <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python</string>
    <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python</string>
</array>
<key>PythonInfoDict</key>
<dict>
    <key>PythonExecutable</key>
    <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3</string>
    <key>PythonLongVersion</key>
    <string>3.9.2 (v3.9.2:1a79785e3e, Feb 19 2021, 09:06:10) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]</string>
    <key>PythonShortVersion</key>
    <string>3.9</string>
    <key>py2app</key>
    <dict>
        <key>alias</key>
        <true/>
        <key>template</key>
        <string>app</string>
        <key>version</key>
        <string>0.24</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

At the command line I then typed the following:

```
codesign -s "PaulF" determinant_calculator.app
```

I was asked for my keychain login and things seemed to work okay. (At least I didn't obtain any error messages.) Now within the determinant_calculator.app bundle contents, I see a new folder called _CodeSignature.

I shared the .app with a different computer via Dropbox after first compressing the file.

However, when I unzipped the file on the new computer and double-clicked it, I obtained the error message, *"determinant_calculator" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.*

This is my first time attempting to notarize an application, and my Python script was quite simple, using only tkinter and numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not only need to codesign your app, you also need to notarize it (as a separate step). If your run the following command in the folder where your app is located, it will send the app to Apple to check. Apple will return a ticket ID. You can then check your notarization history after a few minutes to see if the notarization passed:

Notarization command:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.yourname.yourappname" --username "YourAppleID@mail.com" --password "@keychain:Developer-altool" --file "helloworld.zip"
```

Notarization history check command:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-history 0 --username "YourAppleID@mail.com" --password "@keychain:Developer-altool"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel like I'm finally getting the hang of how this all works.

Comment: You're welcome! It's super complicated, isn't it? One thing I should have added is that you also need to 'staple' the notarization receipt to the app with the following command:
xcrun stapler staple "helloworld.zip"